# Which is better for making a card game SVG or canvas using kinetic.js or oCanvas library?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Which is better for making a card game SVG or canvas using kinetic.js or oCanvas library ?

in terms of performance, event handling and keeping track of objects..

also please let me know if there is a better framework out there which will help me to maje

the game up and running asap. any related sources of knowledge are welcomed.

Thank You

Comment: Cody Gray: Can be better a Silver color? the White gets dirty most notably.

Answer (score 2):

disclaimer: I created KineticJS

I would certainly go with KineticJS because it was built from the ground up around event handling.  I've been playing close attention to my other two favorite libraries, fabric.js and paper.js (awesome libraries), but they don't seem to handle events as well as KineticJS.  with KineticJS, you can make drawings and turn them into objects, from which you can then bind event listeners like mouseover, mouseout, mousemove, mouseup, mousedown, click, dblclick, touchstart, touchend, touchmove, dbltap, dragstart, dragmove, dragend, etc.

From some other demos I've seen, I think KineticJS outperforms other libraries as well (KineticJS has several demos that use 10,000 shapes for stress testing).  Plus it has very strong mobile support.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanx Eric .. 

As it's a simple card game(sweep/seep) I made it using jQuery UI ..

sweepgame.com